# Qt TextEdit smooth scrolling

Tags: qt, scroll, qplaintextedit

In Qt, is it possible to have "smooth scrolling" in a text area? I mean, there is this Qt demo called "Code Editor" which uses `QPlainTextEdit` for an editable text area. When I scroll the area it always jumps one whole row at a time, i.e. the top most row is always displayed fully.

In HTML, for example, text area scrolls its content "smoothly", that is, it is possible to scroll its content even by just one pixel, making the upper row partially hidden.

Is it possible to have this kind of behavior in Qt? Perhaps by using different widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QTextEdit` in "syntaxhighlighter" example scrolls smoothly.